# OpenERP 7 error loading in browser

Tags: odoo

I installed OpenERP 7 in Cent OS Final 6.4 and Python 2.6.6 i=with static ip

I accessed from an outside network using internet it works well

But i accessed within the network it throws an error

Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Template 'WebClient' not found

Comment: are you using a reverse proxy? DNAT?

Comment: @senthilnathang how you fix that ?

Comment: @KorrIamnot the problem is coz of firewall by isp provider airtel

Comment: @KorrIamnot does the solution worked for you ? Because it didn't worked for me. I have two internet connections - tikona & airtel, but switching to either didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

now i use version is odoo 9.0 and ubuntu 15.10 and python 2.7.10
i also meet this issue. And release issue with later.
use

```
ajax.loadXML('/web_editor/static/src/xml/snippets.xml', qweb);
```

to load this xml files,and sinppets.xml maybe like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="web_editor.snippets">
        <div id='oe_snippets' class="hidden-xs o_open">
            <div id="o_arrow">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-1x" style="top: 10px;">
                </span>
                <div>Insert Blocks</div>
                <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-1x" style="bottom: 10px;">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="o_left_bar">
                <span class='snippets_loading'>Snippets are loading...
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>

var ajax = require('web.ajax');
var core = require('web.core');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');   
var qweb = core.qweb;

ajax.loadXML('/web_editor/static/src/xml/snippets.xml', qweb);
var BuildingBlock = Widget.extend({
    template: 'web_editor.snippets',
    init: function (parent, $editable) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    start: function() {....
  }
});
```

and now, none issue.
good luck~